# How to create a per user service on windows?

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, desktop

As per this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows windows 10 now supports per user services . But i could not find any documentation on how to create my own per user service. Is it possible to create per user services in windows?

Answer (score 4):

I have not tested this, but according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicew) it should be sufficient to specify either of the following in the `dwServiceType` parameter to `CreateService`:

- SERVICE_USER_OWN_PROCESS (0x50)
- SERVICE_USER_SHARE_PROCESS (0x60)

See my article [Per-User Services in Windows: Info & Configuration](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2021/01/per-user-services-in-windows-info-and-configuration/) for background information.